# Relative height for list view in column in a scroll view

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am trying to add a list view (horizontal) inside a column which is in a single child scroll view. I have seen recommendations like setting fixed height or using shrink-wrap or using expandable. But none of these are adaptive, how can I set adaptive (relative) height ?

I tried using fractionally sized box, but it does not seem to work.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32),
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Text("Sticky Header"),
        Expanded(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 200, // --> How can I avoid this and make this relative to parent ?
                  child: ListView(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    children: [
                      for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) Text("List: $i"),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) Text("Horizontal: $i"),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap it in `Expanded` or `Flexible` instead of SizedBox.

```
children: [
            Expanded(
              child: ListView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                children: [
                  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) Text("List: $i"),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) Text("Horizontal: $i"),
          ],
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That does not work, I tried before: `════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.`

Comment: `When a column is in a parent that does not provide a finite height constraint, for example if it is in a vertical scrollable, it will try to shrink-wrap its children along the vertical axis. Setting a flex on a child (e.g. using Expanded) indicates that the child is to expand to fill the remaining space in the vertical direction.
These two directives are mutually exclusive. If a parent is to shrink-wrap its child, the child cannot simultaneously expand to fit its parent.`